# Is there any way to get a full iOS crash log when debugging?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Is there any way to get a full iOS crash log when debugging?

For example... I have my phone plugged in, code open, run the app in Debug mode, and the app crashes on a specific line of code. Is there any way to get the crash log from that?

Or do I actually need to be disconnected from the debugger and computer, crash the app, and then get the crash log via the Organizer? I'd prefer to not do it this away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to get the equivalent of a crash log when the debugger is attached.  I would say the general thought is that if the debugger is attached, you should be able to extract any information you need using the debugger itself. Some might argue that it's a *feature* that crash logs aren't generated when you're debugging.

Regardless, you should be able to get all of that info in the debugger. For all thread backtraces you can do:

```
thread apply all bt
```

And for library load addresses you can do:

```
info sharedlibrary
```

That seems to be the bulk of the useful information in a crash log.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode has a built-in consolle. Show it by clicking this button http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/46/schermata012455942alle2.png/ in the top right angle of the window.

Comment: I know that... but how do I get a full stack dump from the console?

Comment: @EthanAllen -- You realize, of course, that if you're stopped at the error, the call stack is present in the debugger stack window.  And there is a way to add logic to your `main` to dump the stack to the console when an exception ripples back to `main`.